# display video from h264 stream of an ip camera in android

Tags: android, h.264, ip-camera

In my ndroid application, I need to display `H264 streams` from a `GrandStream IP Camera`. I saw some topics about decoding H264 frames with `MediaCodec` in Android, but I really don't know where to start.
Before searching this topic, I thought that there were planty of open source library for that purpose but It seems there is not!
Can you show me a way where to start? Should I use `Android's MediaCodec` or is there any open source `Java library` for that?

Comment: Do you find solution for this displaying video from ip camera ? I am finding solution for this

Comment: @yusufonder you can have a look at Vitamio library. it is open source project that has free version. And it behaves like android's media player class and can play H264 videos.

Comment: Yes I know vitamio library but It doesn't work. My question url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134948/video-cannot-be-played-android-vitamio-library. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [site](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/), It has a very thoroughly discussion and sample about Android Media Codec